# Using FFMPEG, how to join two videos with an intermediate crossfade transition?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG, I need to join Video 1 and Video 2 with an intermediate transition Video T .

- Video 1 has a duration D1 .
- Video 2 has a duration D2 .
- Video T should have a duration DT .
- The resulting video should have a duration D1 + DT + D2 .
- Video T should start with a copy of the end frame of Video 1.
- Video T should end with a copy of the start frame of Video 2.
- Video T should be a crossfade from its start frame to its end frame.
- Video 1 and Video 2 are MP4 files and have the same encoding parameters.
- Video 1 and Video 2 contain audio, that should remain in the resulting video.
- Video T should have no audio.

How can Video T be generated, using FFMPEG simply ?

How can Video 1 and Video 2 be joined with the intermediate Video T, using FFMPEG simply ?

Note : I would prefer to perform the entire operation, through a single FFMPEG call.

Note : I would prefer to avoid setting offsets, since D1, D2 and DT may vary.

Comment: Why do you need a video T at all?

Comment: Video T needs to be within the resulting video, but it does not need to be saved separately.

Comment: Video T is needed, to obtain a crossfade transition from Video 1 to Video 2.

Comment: You just need to crossfade directly between 1 and 2. Maybe apply tpad to extend the streams if you want.

Comment: Indeed I probably need to use tpad, to extend Video 1 and 2.  Thank you for the hint !

Comment: But is it possible to crossfade without setting offsets, since D1, D2 and DT may vary ?